# How do I change file/folder ownership on a remote server without access to the commandline?

Tags: php, ftp, mediawiki, chown, directadmin

I've only got access to the directadmin panel (and ftp access as well), and for my mediawiki install I need to change the ownership of a particular folder (so `chown`). More specifically, I need to do this:

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data images/`

Is there a way to do this without the commandline? With directadmin or via ftp?

Comment: I don't think you can do without ssh. But you can try to do that using PHP though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CHOWN doesn't work over FTP and SFTP, the FTP protocol doesn't support it. You'll either need direct access or
>   a full blown SSH2 remote shell.
>
> In DirectAdmin you can only 'reset' ownership through "File Manager".

Comment: `In DirectAdmin you can only 'reset' ownership through "File Manager".`, yeah that's what I saw as well. And resetting ownership doesn't help in this case. Ok, so basically it's not possible with the limitations in this situation, right?

Comment: @Sam, Correct. (You could ask the server admin perhaps). Good Luck :)

Comment: Are you quoting that from somewhere? If so, where?

Answer (score 0):

filezilla and other well known ftp client supports to change permission of file and folder on server. Also you can use umask for changing permissions using php. Then there is not any need for command line access.

Comment: OP wants to change ownership, not permissions.

Comment: Then FTP doesn't supports this. try to use chown in php.

Comment: Actually, some versions of FTP do support it (albeit it's not part of RFC959) the HELP command will tell you if it's available. And why assume that the PHP user has adequate permission to change the ownership of the files?

Comment: @symcbean, "Actually, some versions of FTP do support it". — I'm curious to know which 'versions' exactly?